# SQL Server Self Join and more

Tags: sql-server, self-join

I have a School, with Classes, Teacher, Students, Parents, and so on

In `USERS` table I collect all People related to school using `Role` field as category:

```
ID  USERID      ROLE        CLASS       PARENTOF        SUBJECTS
13  CarolineW   parent                  BillB    
12  IsabelF     parent                  AlexC    
11  SaraW       teacher                                 MATH-3a,MATH-4a,MATH-5b
10  JohnT       teacher                                 ENG4a,GEO2a
9   MatildaW    student     4a       
8   JohnC       student     4a       
7   AlexC       student     4a       
6   CamillaH    student     4a       
5   BillB       student     2a       
4   AnnG        student     1a
```

I want to be able to select (for sending a mail for example) all parents of students of class "4a" for example, or to all people in relation with students of class "4a" (thus student, teacher and parents)

What I'm not able to perform is to select all person related to that Class:
I think I have to perform a self join.. something like this:

```
select distinct 
    A1.userid,
    A1.name, 
    A1.Role, 
    A1.ClassRoom 
from Users A1 
left join Users A2 
    on A1.ParentOf=A2.UserID
left join Users A3 
    on CHARINDEX('4a',A3.Subjects) > 0
```

and it works.. but if I add a filter like `where class='4a'`, clearly does not show me teacher and parents

but my skills do no allows me to go further..

can someone indicate me the right path?

Thanks

Gio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be simpler to get the results using `UNION`

```
select userid, 
       role, class
from users 
where class ='4a'
union all
select userid,
       role, '4a'
from users
where CHARINDEX('4a',Subjects) > 0
union all
select u2.userid, 
       u2.role, '4a'
from users u1
join users u2
on u1.class = '4a'
and u2.parentof = u1.userid
order by role
```

Comment: I can clearly understand what you did: with first you select all students, with second the teachers, and with third the parents..

But I can't improve it to achieve  my final target, that is:

Selecting an user send to all related users according to their role:

ie:
Selecting a Student I would email him or his Parents or Both of them, or his teachers or all 3 different roles

Selecting a Class, email all students/all their Parents/both/all Teachers/all 3

Selecting a Teacher, email all Students/Parents/Both/Teacher/All 3

which approach to use to avoid writing 30 different queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a common table expression if you'd like  It may be easier.  For example, to find all parents with students in a particular class, you would do this:

```
--Variables for testing
DECLARE @classid VARCHAR(10)
SET @classid='2a'

--Common table expression
;WITH students
AS
(
SELECT
[USERID]
FROM USERS
WHERE [CLASS]=@classid
)

,parents
AS
(
SELECT 
u.[USERID]
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN students s ON u.[PARENTOF]=s.[USERID]
)

SELECT USERID FROM parents
```